# Правила употребления "эта" и "следующая" относительно дней недели

Tags: грамматика

Возник спор.

"Сегодня вторник. В следующую пятницу собрание."

Так когда собрание? На текущей неделе или через неделю?

Спасибо.

Comment: В таких случаях лучше не выдумывать ребусы, а сказать, что собрание на следующей неделе в пятницу. Тем более что предыдущая пятница - это прошедшая, а следующая - не понятно что имеет ввиду говорящий, ведь и говорящий может иметь ввиду совсем другое.

Answer (score 2):

Через неделю.

Если "Сегодня вторник. В следующую пятницу собрание", то и подразумевается не текущая неделя, а та, что следует за ней, то есть не через два дня, а через девять. Иначе слово "следующая" лишнее в информации.

Answer (score 0):

О правилах в данном случае говорить не приходится - можно рассуждать лишь о наитии и о заботе об однозначности, либо об отсутствии таковой. Если бы говорящий в вашем примере стремился к ясности и однозначности, то он бы добавил: "... в следующую пятницу, **такого-то числа** (месяца и года, если необходимо отвести всякую угрозу недопонимания со стороны слушателей. Особенно, если новый год наступает, например, *в этот четверг*. - Кстати, какой-нибудь офисный зомби из начальства, почти раздувающийся у вас на глазах от нескончаемых приливов собственного самомнения и самолюбования, мог бы прибегнуть и к канцеляриту (из желания подчеркнуть деловой, сухой стиль своего выступления): например, *(ноль) седьмого ноль девятого двадцать четвёртого)* - собрание."
Моё наитие подсказывает, что @Galina Avanesova права: *скорее всего* говорящий в вашем примере подразумевает, что собрание состоится через 9 дней, а не через 2. В противоположном случае он должен был бы сказать: "...В *эту* пятницу - собрание." Здесь уточнения с конкретной датой были бы, пожалуй, избыточными. С другой стороны, мнимое многословие, служащее единственно победе над размытым смыслом (и над бесплодной серьёзностью), достойно оправдания.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что правильно сказать, обозначив конкретную дату. Следующая пятница каждую неделю до бесконечности.